# Align a div to the bottom of its parent div while maintaining the parent height of 100VH and not using fixed positioning

Tags: html, css

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cwverdkt/.

I am trying to keep "hello" in the center and the photo of the dog on the bottom left. I need the main div to be 100vh and not relative because I am going to implement parallax scrolling and I can't have the dog always be on the bottom.

I have tried:

```
#photo{
  bottom: 0;
}
```

and

```
#photo{
  display: inline-block;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

and

```css
.bottom-aligner {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-aligner">
  <div id="dog">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/FleWUfc.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The last one sort of worked except it cropped the photo of the dog.

Here's a screenshot of what I want to make it look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just added CSS below mentioned. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Vadivel123/2c14x0pq/6/) try this

```
#slide3{display:table}
#photo {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. When I demo, I see that "hello" is no longer centered and that the dog is still not all the way aligned to the bottom.

Comment: Can share screenshot what you expect?

Comment: Can you check now?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot.

Comment: @Brandon Hu Updated demo link check now

Answer (score 0):

Make the dog image as a background of the #photo element to create a parallax scroll effect.

```css
#slide3{
background-color: #fff;
color: #333333;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto;
background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
}

#hello{
 display: table;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width:100px;
}

#photo{
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/FleWUfc.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50%;
  background-position: center bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide3">
  <div id=photo>
    <img src = "https://res-2.cloudinary.com/crunchbase-production/image/upload/c_lpad,h_256,w_256,f_auto,q_auto:eco/w3j8mozntf75fcku9zlr" id = "hello">
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras commodo sit amet tellus ut volutpat. Vestibulum sagittis commodo ultrices. Nunc ullamcorper urna sit amet lobortis posuere. Mauris viverra, leo ut hendrerit hendrerit, turpis lorem porttitor sem, ac tincidunt eros tortor et orci. Praesent aliquam est ac nisl dignissim, quis ullamcorper augue consectetur. Vestibulum ultricies sodales dictum. Nam et tortor vel ante dapibus ornare id sit amet turpis. Pellentesque metus magna, auctor vitae egestas sed, lobortis vitae magna. Quisque at lacus leo. Donec sodales erat et semper feugiat. Donec convallis, diam nec auctor facilisis, sem leo vestibulum enim, eu gravida mi sapien in elit. Donec et magna vel est malesuada sollicitudin. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla pulvinar tempus mi, eu porttitor enim mattis eu. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
    </p>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras commodo sit amet tellus ut volutpat. Vestibulum sagittis commodo ultrices. Nunc ullamcorper urna sit amet lobortis posuere. Mauris viverra, leo ut hendrerit hendrerit, turpis lorem porttitor sem, ac tincidunt eros tortor et orci. Praesent aliquam est ac nisl dignissim, quis ullamcorper augue consectetur. Vestibulum ultricies sodales dictum. Nam et tortor vel ante dapibus ornare id sit amet turpis. Pellentesque metus magna, auctor vitae egestas sed, lobortis vitae magna. Quisque at lacus leo. Donec sodales erat et semper feugiat. Donec convallis, diam nec auctor facilisis, sem leo vestibulum enim, eu gravida mi sapien in elit. Donec et magna vel est malesuada sollicitudin. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla pulvinar tempus mi, eu porttitor enim mattis eu. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
    </p>
    <div id = "dog">
      <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/FleWUfc.png"/>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```